spring kafka start reading from the start of a topic
So i have my config as follows:
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=host
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group-1
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

listener annoation:
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")

I changed the group id from group-0 to group-1 hoping ti would start reading again. But the listener doesn't do that. What do i need to do to get the service to start reading again from the start?

If group1 already existed for the topics you're trying to consume, then it's not expected to start anywhere except where it left off
auto-offset-reset=earliest does exactly what you want. If you need to call seekToBeginning or kafka-console-consumer --reset-offsets, then do so
